# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in Kendo Pivot Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui-mvc

I am working with Kendo Pivot Grid. When I expand row I get error in console.

> Cannot read property '`value`' of undefined.

Before I get error I was refresh datasource with JavaScript and I didn't remove Measures and dimensions.

When I remove Measures and dimensions and after that refresh datasource everything is okay and I don't get error above.

```
$("#pivotgrid").data("kendoPivotGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Has anyone else had this error? I have the same exact scenario.

Answer (score 2):

After searching around I finally found the answer to this and thought I'd share so future seekers will have an answer. When you want to refresh the data on a Kendo Pivot Grid you should call `trigger("stateReset")` on the dataSource before calling `read()`.

Something like this should work:

```
var grid =  $("#grid").data("kendoPivotGrid").dataSource;
grid.trigger("stateReset");
grid.read();
```

Found here after a lot of digging: [Source](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/pivotgrid/how-to/dimensions/reset-expand-state)